# How to point a domain to another address without access to add CNAME zone

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, cname-record

Ive bought some domains from a hosting service and i want to point them to my other server. I did so usually by adding a DNS zone of type CNAME to list of DNS es which is set in my domain administration panel. but unfortunately I do not have access to add a CNAME, I can only change my name servers. I have even tried to point the name servers to my own domain name server, but this did not work so. for example I have the name servers ns1.online4iran.com and ns2.online4iran.com. but the domain still does not point to my server. is there a way to handle this situation. shall I start a spicific service on my server to handle this thing? or should I preform specific configurations on my own domain configuration page?

thanks,

Comment: would be easier if you post a name of domain that have problems

Answer (score 3):

To change the authoritative DNS servers for the domain, you should contact your domain provider, who will be able to change the authoritative nameservers.

Even if you could add CNAME, do not do it for domain.tld, it is not "allowed" as CNAME records are not allowed to co-exist along with other records. See [RFC 1912](http://rfc.frands.net/rfc1912.txt) 2.4

Answer (score 0):

To make domain work you need (In reverse order):

1. Have you webserver setup for your new domain (if it's shared hosting it will not work if hosting doesn't know about the domain, if it isn't shared it may be not necessary to setup anything) - guess this step is not a problem.
2. Have "A" record for example.com and www.example.com point to webserver IP. (You used to achive the same with CNAME (CNAME is a DNS record, NOT zone) pointing to some domain that in turn have the A record - isn't strictly correct way but could work)
3. Have a nameserver that will hold zone for yuor domain (CNAME is a DNS record, NOT zone).
4. Have parent domain nameservers refer to your nameservers for your domain (This is what you refer to when you say you can only change nameservers)

Thus you need a nameserver. Either you setup your new domains on online4iran nameservers, or sign-up for some 3-rd party nameservers (for free options see [the biased list](http://talkdns.info/list)) and configure there zones for your domains with the A records (or CNAME if you insist)